# 'Can't create node with labels or properties here. The variable is already declared in this context' in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just downloaded and installed Neo4j 3.0.0 about ten minutes ago. I am creating a graph database with Neo4j.

When I try to run 3 statements at once, I get an error:

`Can't create node 'famA' with labels or properties here. The variable is already declared in this context`

(This is where I'm attempting to put in a definition node).

I am not sure what the problem is. My first thought was that I need to carry along variables across blocks, since I've had this problem before, but that seems to be a different case (sorry, I'm still new to Neo4j).

Looking at what is going on with `famA`, it is only declared once, and it seems like the syntax is okay?  It's all right here:

```
// Create the definition node:
CREATE 
    (famA:Family {family_ID:'A'}) 
    WITH famA
    MATCH (a:Person {name:"a"})-[*]-(b:Person)  
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(a) 
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(b)
```

I also want to note, my script worked fine last week -- maybe this is some problem with a new version?

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Here's the code to create the db:

```
// First family:  family_ID = A.  This family has 3 members with Alzheimers who are not alive, and more than half of them are Left handed
CREATE 
    (   a:Person {name: 'a',    id:'1', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    ( aSP:Person {name: 'aSP',  id:'2', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (   b:Person {name: 'b',    id:'3', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Normal',     `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    ( bSP:Person {name: 'bSP',  id:'4', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Right', `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (bSib:Person {name: 'bSib', id:'5', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'MCI',        `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (   c:Person {name: 'c',    id:'6', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'MCI',        `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Right', `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    (cSib:Person {name: 'cSib', id:'7', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers',  `Is Alive?`: 'Yes', Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'})

CREATE
    (a)-[:SPOUSE]->(aSP),
    (b)-[:CHILD]->(a),
    (b)-[:CHILD]->(aSP),
    (b)-[:SPOUSE]->(bSP),
    (bSib)-[:SIBLING]->(b),
    (bSib)-[:CHILD]->(aSP),
    (c)-[:CHILD]->(b),
    (c)-[:CHILD]->(bSP),
    (cSib)-[:SIBLING]->(c),
    (cSib)-[:CHILD]->(bSP)

// Create the definition node:
CREATE 
    (famA:Family {family_ID:'A'}) 
    WITH famA
    MATCH (a:Person {name:"a"})-[*]-(b:Person)  
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(a) 
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove label from `famA merge` (if you use the `merge` with label - it will be an indication of the node creation, but this node previously created):

```
// Create the definition node:
CREATE 
    (famA:Family {family_ID:'A'}) 
    WITH famA
    MATCH (a:Person {name:"a"})-[*]-(b:Person)  
    MERGE (famA)<-[:FAMILY]-(a) 
    MERGE (famA)<-[:FAMILY]-(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I had to change this:

```
MATCH (ks1:KbWordSequence) 
MATCH (ks2:KbWordSequence {kbidseq: ks1.kbidseqnxt})
CREATE (ks1)-[:NEXT]->(ks2)
MERGE (ks1:KbWordSequence)-[:NEXT]->(ks2:KbWordSequence {kbidseqnxt: ks1.kbidseq})
```

to this:

```
MATCH  (ks1:KbWordSequence) 
MATCH  (ks2:KbWordSequence {kbidseq: ks1.kbidseqnxt})
CREATE (ks1)-[:NEXT]->(ks2)
MERGE  (ks1)-[:NEXT]->(ks2) 
        SET ks2.kbidseqnxt = ks1.kbidseq
```

Basically I wasn't allowed to set node values in the second MERGE statement, I had to add a SET on that merge.